# Reuse element/class with JAXB unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, code-reuse

I have this XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<specie name="Puma concolor" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="species.xsd">
<longevity>
    <lifeSpan type="wild">
      <min type="y">18</min>
      <max type="y">20</max>
    </lifeSpan>
    <lifeSpan type="captivity">
      <avg type="y">20</avg>
    </lifeSpan>
  </longevity>
<reproduction>
    <matingSystem>polygamous/polygynous</matingSystem>
    <gestation>
      <min type="d">84</min>
      <max type="d">106</max>
    </gestation>
  </reproduction>  
</specie>
```

I've created three classes Min, Max and Avg like this:

```
package speciejaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlType(name = "max")
public class Max {

  private int _value;

  public int getValue() {
    return _value;
  }

  @XmlValue
  public void setValue(int value) {
    this._value = value;
  }

  private String _type;

  public String getType() {
    return _type;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public void setType(String type) {
    this._type = type;
  }
}
```

How can I reuse this classes inside "longevity" class/element and inside "reproduction/breedingInterval" class/element? Or do I have to duplicate them and create LongevityMin adn BreedingMin with the same code? What about setter/getter from upper classes?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it. First some POJOs:

```
public class Specie {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String name;
    @XmlWrapperTag("longevity")
    @XmlName("lifeSpan")
    public List<LifeSpan> lifespans;
    public Reproduction reproduction;
}
public class LifeSpan {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String type;
    public Max max;
    public Max min;
    public Max avg;
}
public class Max {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String type;
    @XmlTextNode
    public int value;
}
public class Reproduction {
    public String matingSystem;
    public Gestation gestation;
}
public class Gestation {
    public Max max;
    public Max min;
}
```

Note that I'm re-using the Max class in various places, I don't think it should be called Max though.
Next we serialize the XML to an object and print some values:

```
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Specie s = simple.fromXml(xml, Specie.class);
System.out.println(s.reproduction.gestation.min.value);
System.out.println(s.lifespans.get(1).avg.value);
```

This will print:

```
84
20
```

SimpleXml is in maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```